# Cors Policy No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, cors

Im taking a [course](https://www.udemy.com/course/full-stack-application-development-with-spring-boot-and-angular) Angular And Spring Boot on Udemy and I keep encountering this error

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/Karnage' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource"

I have checked every question here that has the word cors in it, it has me at a dead stop for more than a week of constant research.

Spring Class:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController


public class HelloWorldController {
    
    

    
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world-bean")
    public HelloWorldBean helloWorldBean() {
        //throw new RuntimeException("some error has occurd");
        return new HelloWorldBean ("Hello World");
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world/path-variable/{name}")
    public HelloWorldBean helloWorldPathVariable(@PathVariable String name) 
    {
        return new HelloWorldBean(String.format("Hello World, %s", name));
    }

}
```

Spring Basic Authentication:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()   
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //.formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
    
    
}
```

Angular Welcome-Data-Serivce:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class HelloWorldBean {
  constructor(public message: string) { }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WelcomeDataService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  executeHelloWorldBeanService() {
    return this.http.get<HelloWorldBean>('http://localhost:8080/hello-world-bean');
  }

  executeHelloWorldServiceWithPathVariable(name: any) {
    let basicAuthHeaderString = this.createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader();

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString

    })


    return this.http.get<HelloWorldBean>(
      `http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/${name}`,
      { headers }
    );
  }

  createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader() {
    let username = 'karnage'
    let password = '123'
    let basicAuthHeaderString = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
    return basicAuthHeaderString;
  }

}
```

Angular Welcome Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeDataService } from '../service/data/welcome-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  welcomeMessageFromService: any
  name = ''
  constructor(
    private service: WelcomeDataService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name = this.router.snapshot.params['name']

  }

  getWelcomeMessage() {
    //console.log(this.service.executeHelloWorldBeanService());
    this.service.executeHelloWorldBeanService().subscribe(

      response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),

      error => this.handleErrorResponse(error)
    );
  }

  getWelcomeMessageWithPath() {
    //console.log(this.service.executeHelloWorldBeanService());
    this.service.executeHelloWorldServiceWithPathVariable(this.name).subscribe(

      response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),

      error => this.handleErrorResponse(error)
    );
  }


  handleSuccessfulResponse(response: any) {

    console.log(response)
    this.welcomeMessageFromService = response.message
  }

  handleErrorResponse(error: any) {
    console.log(error)
    this.welcomeMessageFromService = error.error.message
  }
}
```

[image]

much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem while updating the project and fixed the problem using the plugin.
`Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Install the plugin and then refresh that page.  It may need to be repeated several times

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: I tried that already it gives me an another cors error which is "https status ok"

Comment: Please help me i still couldn't find a fix for this..